# showing Json data in datatable

Tags: json, datatables-1.10

I used the jquery datatable plugin.I want to show a JSON data in the datatable.

```
Object {Titillium-Light: "data1", Custom font: "data2", Titillium-Bold: "data3", Titillium-LightUpright: "data4"}
```

i want show the keys in json in one column and value of the key in another column.
I dont know how to give the reference in mDataProp.

```
aoColumns: [
                {
                    sTitle: 'ID',
                    mDataProp: ,
                    bVisible:  false
                },
                {
                    sTitle: 'data',
                    mDataProp: ,
                }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample data is a literal, not JSON. It should look like

```
var json = { 
  "Titillium-Light": "data1", 
  "Custom font": "data2", 
  "Titillium-Bold": "data3", 
  "Titillium-LightUpright": "data4"
}
```

Then, if you have an empty table

```
<table id="example"></table>
```

You could construct a key->value dataset based on the JSON :

```
var data = [];
for (key in json) {
   data.push({
      key: key,
      value: json[key]
   })
}
```

and use that dataset as source for the dataTable :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data : data,
    columns : [
      { title: 'key', data: 'key'},
      { title: 'value', data: 'value'}
    ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sh8mr7cq/**